# How do I keep credentials in a node module private?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

It's basically in the title. If all node modules are open source, how do you keep usernames and passwords private? Like so:

```
// code
db.connect(username, password);
// more code
```

Any downloader of the module would be able to see the credentials. How do I make it so they can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you would load credentials from a configuration file (not from your publicly shared code) and only a shell of a configuration file would be included in the public repository.

In node.js, one of the easiest ways to read a configuration file is to make the data in the file be JSON, give the file a `.json` file extension an then you can just load it with `require()` as in:

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

Comment: So how would you access this config file without sharing it in the module?

Comment: @bjskistad - I don't understand what you're asking.  When you install the code, part of the setup process is that you manually create/edit the config file you need just like you would manually install and create the right database.  You can then put the config file wherever you want and use an appropriate path with `require()` to reach it.  The module references the config file, but you don't put a fully functional config file in the public repository.  You only put the config file in the safe server-side directory where you keep your server source files while running them.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't include credentials in a node module, That would be considered bad practice. You'd provide some way for a user of the node module to provide their own credentials. For example, if the module exported a class. You could have a class constructor which takes the username and password.

Also all node modules aren't open source. NPM offers the ability to host private packages as well ( for a fee ) , or you have something like sinopia , which lets you self host a package registry to use with npm.

Comment: If you don't put creds in a module, then how does heroku connect to it's DB?

Comment: If you wrote a node module, and published it to npm, you'd never store credentials in that node module. Anyone that required that node module would provide credentials via something like I mentioned above. For example, in a project, you could require the 'fb' node module, which you can use to access Facebooks SDK. This module has a 'setAccessToken' function, which allows you to provide credentials to the module to access certain SDK functions.

Comment: Have a look at 12factor.net.  It'll be pretty enlightening for you on all sorts of best practices.